# Problem load websocket service and laravel and vue.js on Server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, websocket, server

### I have problem on websocket ... I write project to send and receive realtime data in laravel with websocket and vue.js. It is working on the localhost... I uploded the project on the server and doesn't work on the server

I think there is problem on pusher key ....

Anybody can help me ????

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem setting up websocket to the production server. Then I moved to [Laravel Echo Server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server). You can use that pretty easily, no need to change much in your code. just remember to provide `authHost, sslCertPath, sslKeyPath` to the server's configuration file. And I ran the service with pm2. I had problem setting up '[supervisor](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps)'. (My production environment was ubuntu). If you have ubuntu too, you can first try to keep the websocket working with supervisor or pm2, if it still doesn't work, you can switch to Laravel Echo Server like me. Choice is yours!

Comment: thank you. may you give me telegram or whatsapp or instagram to speak and help better???.

Comment: You can mail me directly : tamzid.gregorian@gmail.com